# Text transition on hover image

Tags: css, image, hover, overlay

I'am trying to set css transition on the text on hover image like this -> https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/portfolio-grid/

I tried to do this with cubic-bezier() function, but without result.

Here's my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 257px;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <img class="img__img" src="http://placehold.it/257x200.jpg" />
  <p class="img__description">Teext.</p>
</div>
```

Please give me some hints how to do this.

Comment: Which effect are you looking for? zooming image? moving text? wrap opacity?

Comment: Im looking for mooving text effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To darken the image, you need to change the opacity of it. To zoom the image, use a scale transform and to move the caption text, you need a translateX transform. Apply those css styles and their respective transitions (you need a transition in the image as well as in the text) and you're left with the following:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 257px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.img__img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.img__description {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
    left: 15px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
  
.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <img class="img__img" src="http://placehold.it/257x200.jpg" />
  <p class="img__description">Teext.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `transform: translate();` to move object. Play with cubic-bezier [here](https://easings.net/#) to achieve perfect animation. But I used the same which was on the website you posted in example. 
Also I removed `opacity`, `visibility`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}


.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 257px;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.095, 1.08);
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <img class="img__img" src="http://placehold.it/257x200.jpg" />
  <p class="img__description">Teext.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, I would suggest using "all" for the transition element instead of defining the same values for all of the proprieties you want to transition.

```
transition: all .2s;
```

Second, let's get the bezier right. I think this is close enough:

```
cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.215, 0.355, 0.990)
```

So the transition propriety should look like this:

```
transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.215, 0.355, 0.990);
```

For the text animation I suggest using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and use fadeInLeft.